# Unable to import Maven Project in Eclipse as Next and Finish buttons are disabled

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Initially, I have imported Maven Project to eclipse then got deleted accidentally from Workspace, and delete project contents on disk were unchecked.

I tried to import the Maven project again to eclipse but facing Next and Finish buttons are disabled though have deleted .m2, .eclipse, .mc-ad, .p2 from the user's folder. There is no settings.xml in the Users folder.

I have installed Eclipse in another place also, and tried, but Observed the same behavior.

Could you please update me on how to import the Maven project again, if deleted from the workspace?

[Eclipse Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjibT.png)

Thanks for your support.

[Project Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d2xl.png)

Comment: most probably there is no pom.xml found in the location you are referring to.

Comment: Don't use Maven import wizard, when a `.project` file already exist. Generally (in all cases, except for Gradle projects), use _File > Import Projects from File System..._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Maven project (pom.xml) in the directory you are looking at. Change the root directory to the directory your project is in (in your case probably not the same as the workspace).

Comment: Actually, it is zipped project got from others and trying to import in my machine

Comment: One way to go would be to unzip the project into the directory of your choice on your machine ant then import it from there to your workspace.

Comment: Thanks JP. I tried that it worked for first time. As i have deleted the imported project accidently and unable to import it again

Comment: So your issue is resolved?

Comment: No. its not resolved.

Comment: Can you show what is in your MavenFramework directory.

Comment: Updated screenshot Project Screenshot

Comment: When you browse your Root Directory select the CRAFT_Maven directory